# Why wont a signed ClickOnce application display the Trusted Publisher?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, deployment, clickonce, digital-certificate

Attached to this question are some pictures to give you guys an idea of what we are doing.

1 The code is signed with a Verisign Class 3 Code.
[image]

2 It's published through Visual Studio to our Web Server.
[image: Published application]

3 When I click on download it displays the warning message.
[image: No Trusted Publisher]

4 It doesn't show the Trusted Publisher.
[image: Extra Information]

The only thing that I believe might be the issue is that one of the projects references the...

Microsoft.Office.Core

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Microsoft.Vbe.Interop

The weird thing is that when the project is installed those dll's are not included in the project so I guess it's getting it from the GAC.

I did create a simple project and just signed it and it worked fine.  But this application is pretty big and removing the Office references would make the program completely un-buildable.

Any suggestions or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The trusted publisher seems to look at the Support url under Publish -> Options on the project.  I was using a long url like the one below to make it crash.

http://www.yourwebsite.com/documents/ABC-&&YTff5643LO$$ccRUim/UserGuides/ABCDEFG/ABCDEFG.pdf

The length, special characters or the fact that it's a file could have cause the issue.

You CAN use regular url links and it will work.